# Does all Layer 3 capable switches able to do Layer 2?

Tags: switch

I was tasked to find an affordable Layer 2 Switch around our area but can't seem to find one... in fact I found a Layer 3 Switch that seems to be cheaper than the Layer 2 i came across somewhere.

I found this Layer 3 Switch 
http://www8.hp.com/emea_africa/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=6783404&jumpid=reg_r1002_emea_africaen_c-001_title_r0001#!tab=features

w/c is ok with our budget... but the Specifications did not mention any Layer 2 stuffs.. Is it safe to assume that LAYER 3 Switches cover layer 2 capabilities as well? Or can switches have one of each only ?

Comment: @Chopper3 answer is correct, but some L3 devices are not as specialized as L2 devices, so check if you need anything "fancy" before buying one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on the existing answer, yes - Layer 3 is 'Routing' and layer 2 is 'Switching'

Layer 1 is 'physical' (is there a cable plugged into the port, that kind of thing)

So to do layer 3, you have to do 2, and to do 2, you have to have 1.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the 'switch' bit that does the L2 stuff.